# Biggest square submatrix with 0s inside and 1s outside

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sub-array

**Task:** I need to make a method that will find biggest *square submatrix* with *1s in border* and *0s inside*, from matrix(2d array) that could be square but doesn't need to be. All elements of matrix are 1s and 0s.

This is my code

```
static void sub(int[][] p){
    int sm=(p[0].length<p.length)?p[0].length:p.length;
    int bg=(p[0].length<p.length)?p.length:p[0].length;
    if(p.length==p[0].length){
        sm=p.length;bg=p.length;
    }
    int t=0;
    boolean cool=false;

    z:for(int z=sm;z>2;z--){
        x:for(int x=0,l=0;x<sm-z;x++,l++){
            y:for(int y=0,m=0;y<bg-z;y++,m++){
                for (int i=y;i<=z+m;i++){
                    if(p[x][i]!=1){cool=false; continue x;}
                    else cool=true;
                    if(p[z][i]!=1){cool=false; continue x;}
                    else cool=true;
                }
                int n=0;
                for(int j=0;j<z-1;j++)
                for(int i=y+1;i<z+m;i++){
                    if(p[x+n][i]!=0){cool=false; continue x;}
                    else cool=true;
                    if(i==z+m-1)n++;
                }
                for (int i=x+1;i<z+l;i++){
                    if(p[i][y]!=1){cool=false; continue x;}
                    else cool=true;
                }
                for(int i=x+1;i<=z-1;i++){
                    if(p[i][z+t]!=1) continue x;
                }
                if(cool){
                    System.out.println(x+" "+y+" "+z);
                }
                t++;
            }
            t=0;
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] p = {
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
    };
    sub(p);
}
```

**Variables:** x and y - starting x and y coordinate (p[x][y])
               z - length of square submatrix

Where's mistake. Why I don't get those x, y and z for this example. I have tested all these for loops they take elements that they should. And if you have some advice, some better way I would like to know. Thanks!

Comment: how many squares are there? is there any guarantee that there will be no zeros outside squares, or ones outside borders?

Comment: The only thing that does matter is that square is biggest with at least one zero inside(surrounded by ones). Ones in border, zero(s)  inside. Biggest possible.

Comment: In your example, there is a rectangle of 0s, but not a square of 0s.

Comment: Omg :) you're right I'll check if code works if I change that. I just pasted those ones on right side. Shame on me.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I set just one square like that and it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand your approach but I think it may be overdoing it a little. For example you have several pieces of code checking whether an element is 0 or 1 when it could be done in one place.

It might help you to take a step back and reevaluate your code. What is it supposed to do?

"I need to make a method that will find biggest square submatrix with 1s in border and 0s inside"
with example:

```
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
```

now I think I can sort of get your approach but let's write it out:

> biggest_square = 0
>
> for every element in the matrix:
>
> if it is the corner of a square
>
> find out how big the square is
>
> set biggest_square to max(square, biggest_square)
>
> end if
>
> end for
>
> return biggest_square

The question now is how to find out the size of the square. To do this we can start a the single zero and then check if the next layer of the square is there.
Like this:

> {0}
>   check next layer
>
> {0 0} ,
>
> {0 0}
>   check next layer
>
> {0 0 0}
>
> {0 0 0}
>
> {0 0 0}
>   check next layer

and so on

To do this we can:

```
while matrix[i][j]==0:
    //check row below bottom of square
    for j =start_j to i:
        if matrix[i][j]!=0:
            break
        i++

    // if the side is short than the current side length
    if i<j:
        break

    //check column to right of square
    for j= start_j to i:
        if matrix[i][j]!=0:
            break
        j++
    //the row below and column to the right have all 0's so add to the square
    biggest_square++
```

A final note on style: it is generally better to space things out and put the start and end of blocks on new lines and to pick descriptive name for variables. I have no idea what the variables sm and bg are meant to be and "cool" isn't particularly descriptive.

Sorry for any errors and I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Well sm is what is smaller length in rows or columns, bg what is bigger. I made those beacause I want from biggest possible square to check smaller ones. First should be the biggest. Cool is a varable that needs to be true till end of y named for loop. Inside of it I check all border elements of square if they are all 1,and one of them is for inside elements to check if they are all zeros. At the end if cool is true it should print out starting x and y coordinate of cool square.

Comment: I tried to move right with square of some size to the end(right in this example) and move for one down then repeat till end.